# rubygems platform specific dependency

Tags: ruby, rubygems

`gem install pomo` does not pull in the dependency libnotify on Linux, which then causes a LoadError at runtime. The problem seems to be that rubygems doesn't know how to deal with [conditionals in the gemfile](https://github.com/tj/pomo/blob/master/pomo.gemspec), and writing [this extension](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/RubyGems#How_to_install_different_versions_of_gems_depending_on_which_version_of_ruby_the_installee_is_using) suggested by the rubygems wikibook didn't help. How are you supposed to express platform-specific dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Bundler.  You configure dependencies using a text file (Gemfile) and it can have platform-specific regions.  I think newer versions of Ruby already have bundler in the gems.

Comment: I thought Bundler was for managing dependencies in development. The project in question already has a Gemfile; the problem is that when I installed it using RubyGems the package manager couldn't parse it correctly and install the libnotify dependency.

Comment: Bundler / Gemfile is also intended for production.  Could there be something wrong in the Gemfile?